Has anyone got FilePond working with apollo-upload-client?
I use a GraphQL API and Next.js frontend and they're integrated with Apollo Upload Client. There's a section of my website where the user can upload files, and upon uploading each file I'd like an endpoint on the GraphQL API, say AddFileMutation, to be called (we use GraphQL Code Generator TypeScript objects to pass the data).
If I remove a file, I'd like endpoint RemoveFileMutation to be called. As well, I want to load files that were previously uploaded (just file names is fine but a link would be nice).
I'd like to use FilePond for all of this since it handles type validation and progress spinners, etc for us. Or happy to take suggestions if anyone knows of another reliable React components file uploader library!
I've taken a look at how FilePond's server API is configured but I'm encountering a few issues. I've also had a look at just using onaddfile and onremovefile but it seems on initial load if I want to show existing files, process on the file is called and so is addFile event and I don't want to re-download those files.
Anyone out there got an example of how I can piece all this together? GraphQL API with getFiles (for the originally uploaded files), addFile and removeFile endpoints Apollo/GraphQL Code Generator, and FilePond?
